# Trying to construct modular exponentiation gate in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm

https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/shor.html in this tutorial I don't understand especially in how they define for the modular exponentiation gate with only swap gate (inside c_amod15 function).

```
def c_amod15(a, power):
    """Controlled multiplication by a mod 15"""
    if a not in [2,4,7,8,11,13]:
        raise ValueError("'a' must be 2,4,7,8,11 or 13")
    U = QuantumCircuit(4)        
    for iteration in range(power):
        if a in [2,13]:
            U.swap(2,3)
            U.swap(1,2)
            U.swap(0,1)
        if a in [7,8]:
            U.swap(0,1)
            U.swap(1,2)
            U.swap(2,3)
        if a in [4, 11]:
            U.swap(1,3)
            U.swap(0,2)
        if a in [7,11,13]:
            for q in range(4):
                U.x(q)
    U = U.to_gate()
    U.name = "%i^%i mod 15" % (a, power)
    c_U = U.control()
    return c_U
```

is not very clear to me how they suddenly come up with this code without a detail explanation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15280/how-does-this-represent-modular-multiplication

Comment: watch the bit pattern change from $x$ to $ax\mod 15$ for a given $a$ value, then compare to the gate generated by this method, you should be able to understand the process.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit represents the operation $x*a^p \mod 15$. In order to implement any arithmetic operation we need to manipulate bits. For simplicity let's put $x=1$. This will allows us to focus on the swap gates.

For example, suppose $a=2$ and $p=3$. Then our operation is $1*2^3 = 1*2*2*2$. Let's work it out in binary. Note that
\begin{align}
1 * 1 &= 1 \equiv 0001 * 0001 = 000\color{red}1.
\end{align}
Then we have:
\begin{align}
\tag{1} 1*2 &= 2 \equiv 0001 * 0010 = 00\color{red}10,\\
2*2 & = 4 \equiv 0010 * 0010 = 0\color{red}100\\
4*2 &= 8 \equiv 0100 * 0010 = \color{red}1000.
\end{align}
The pattern is very clear, repetitive multiplication by $2$ shifts the red bit from right to left. Let's do another multiplication by $2$ to bring it home: $2^3 *2 \mod 15  = 1$. So we get that $2^4 = 1$ in mod $15$. Let's verify this by continuing the multiplication table above:
\begin{align}
4*2 &= 8 \equiv 0100 * 0010 = \color{red}1000\\
8 * 2 &= 1 \equiv 1000 * 0010 = 000\color{red}1.
\end{align}
So we indeed get a cyclic shift from right to left, i.e., we return back to where we have started. So implementing an operation $a^p \mod 15$ amounts to shifting the bit $\color{red}1$. This shift is achieved by doing a series of swaps that exchange the position of $\color{red}1$.

In the example given in Eq (1), we had $p=3$, so it took $3$ iterations to get $2^3 =8$. This is reflected in the code where the variable `power` would be equal to 3:

```
for iteration in range(power):
        if a in [2,13]:
            U.swap(2,3)
            U.swap(1,2)
            U.swap(0,1)
```

The first iteration will shift the bit $\color{red}1$ from the most right to left by one position. The second iteration will shift the bit by one more position. And finally, the third iteration will give $\color{red}1000$.

I hope you can figure out the rest.